# Elementary Q about Swift (1.2) variables

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
var x = 17.0
var y = 1.0
var z = 0.5
var isSq : Bool = true
y = ((sqrt(x)) - Int(sqrt(x)))
```

I am working in Xcode 6.4

Last line produces error: 'could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments'.

Would be nice to understand what is happening here, also is there a function which returns just the decimal part of a double variable - the compliment of Int()?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqrt(x)` has the type `Double`, and `Int(sqrt(x))` has the type
`Int`. There is no minus operator in Swift that takes a `Double` as
left operand and an `Int` as right operand,
and Swift does not implicitly convert between types.

Therefore you have to convert the `Int` to `Double` again:

```
let y = sqrt(x) - Double(Int(sqrt(x)))
```

You can extract the fractional part also with the `fmod()` function:

```
let y = fmod(sqrt(x), 1.0)
```

Comment: Extremely helpful thanks.  May I ask what second parameter of fmod function is??

Comment: @sputnik: You are welcome! – About fmod, have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fmod.3.html or type `man fmod` in a Terminal window. Simply put, `fmod(x, y)` is the floating point variant of `x % y` (the "remainder" operator).